# in header i need to place logo on the left and text exactly at the center of the page header

Tags: html, css, position, css-float, css-position

in header i need to place logo on the left and text exactly at the center of the page header .

I have done it the following two ways

1)

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:2px;width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;padding-top:15px;">
        //logo
        </div>
        <div>
            text
        </div>
</div>
```

but here the text is not exactly at the center

2)

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:2px;">
        <div style="position:absolute">
            logo
        </div>

    <center>
        text
    </center>
</div>
```

This satisfies my goal but both logo and content are dynamic.
so if the text is very large it slides under the img which should not happen

please provide me with an working alternative

Comment: if the logo has position absolute, the text won't slide under it. The problem is that it will go behind it. But you have to deal with that with paddings or something like that. You can't have both width 100% on text , and width depending on logo width so it won't overlap . Position absolute is the way to go. Also..how is the logo dynamic ?

Comment: @MihaiT it is a common platform for various clients

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:2px;width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;padding-top:15px;">
        //logo
        </div>
        <div class="centerPage">
            text
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.centerPage{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
```

The text is now in the center of the page. Is this what you want?